# What's the meaning of MC, PD, FD in Korean TV serial Running Man?

Tags: running-man

I am watching [Running Man](https://www.google.com/search?q=Running%20Man) recently. I noticed that they used MC,PD,FD sometime. I can guess that MC may refer to the host/hostess. After I Google a lot of times, MC may be **Master of ceremonies**. But I am not sure. However I don't know what PD and FD refer to. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that:

- MC is indeed **Host** (since it's what they call host [Yoo Jae-suk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoo_Jae-suk));
- PD is **Program Director** or Production Director (see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33041/whats-the-meaning-of-pd));
- FD is **Floor Director** (see 3rd paragraph [here](http://loreinstonecities.com/2012/11/21/introduction-to-running-man-part-6-behind-the-camera/)).

Comment: Is MC the abbreviation of `Master of ceremonies` ?

Answer (score 0):

MC in Running Man can actually means **Monday Couple**; a pairing of Kang Gary and Song Ji Hyo that starts in the earlier episodes.

Comment: can you add a bit more reference and/or supporting details please

Comment: Nope, MC is the host not the Monday couple according to the context.

Answer (score 0):

MC - Short for master of ceremonies or mic controller. Essentially a word for a rapper but the term is not limited to hip hop.

PD - Producer

Comment: Could you provide some citations or elaborate answer bit if possible

Answer (score 0):

When used in dramas or films, MC means "Main Character".